# Change values in Pandas cells based on value_counts() condition

Tags: python, pandas

How can I change the values in specific columns in pandas dataframe, based on the condition.
This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data':['lemon', 'apple', 'lemon', 'apple', 'apple', 'lemon', 'pear', 'apple', 
                            'pear', 'lemon', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'banana', 'pear']})

     data
0    lemon
1    apple
2    lemon
3    apple
4    apple
5    lemon
6     pear
7    apple
8     pear
9    lemon
10    pear
11  orange
12  banana
13  banana
14    pear
```

Counting each element:

```
lemon     4
apple     4
pear      4
banana    2
orange    1
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

How can I change the value to 'other'if value_counts() result is less than 4?
Expected result:

```
     data
0    lemon
1    apple
2    lemon
3    apple
4    apple
5    lemon
6     pear
7    apple
8     pear
9    lemon
10    pear
11  other
12  other
13  other
14    pear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with counts values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and test if less like `4`:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].mask(df['data'].map(df['data'].value_counts()).lt(4), 'other')
#alternative
df['data'] = df['data'].mask(df.groupby('data')['data'].transform('size').lt(4), 'other')
print (df)
     data
0   lemon
1   apple
2   lemon
3   apple
4   apple
5   lemon
6    pear
7   apple
8    pear
9   lemon
10   pear
11  other
12  other
13  other
14   pear
```

Comment: Thanks, but You wrote lt(4), what If I have values 4,5,6,7,8,9...etc?

Comment: @taga - do you think in`value_counts()` ? then working same, if less like `4` it replace to other. But maybe not understand.

Answer (score 0):

We could apply function like this.

```
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x : 'other' if len(df[df.data==x])<4 else x)
```